# Check if tax is being charged in checkout

Tags: checkout, tax

I need a programmatic way to check if tax is being applied in the checkout. The are situations in the store I'm working on where it either will or won't. The situation being that some countries get charged tax and some don't. This may change so I'd prefer not to check the countries.

I know the following code brings back information which possibly answers the question but it just returns numbers so I'm not sure what they represent.

```
Mage::getStoreConfig(
      'tax/display/type',
      Mage::app()->getStore()
 );
```

I assume this info can be found somewhere in the quote also because when I use `Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal()` it outputs the price with or without tax correctly. I just don't see anything that tells me explicitly - yes this checkout quote has tax applied.

Comment: tax/display/type is set in admin/System/Config/Sales/Tax and says whether you want to display prices ex (1), inc(2), or both(3). It might help to gives some examples of the tax situations.

Comment: I updated the question. I was hoping that there would be a boolean set somewhere stating that tax is or is not applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I had a quick look and I don't think you're going to get a boolean out of it, but maybe I missed the obvious. The closest I think you'll get is to look at `Quote->getShippingAddress()->getAppliedTaxes()` which should give you an array of the taxes being applied to the quote - if the array's empty then there's no tax being applied.

I didn't experiment with multiple shipping addresses and the parameters for whether tax is calculated on billing or shipping address so that may be different for you. Excluding that it looks like it'll take into account the Customer Tax Class, and the Country Tax Settings (and the Product Tax settings as well)

Comment: cheers pal this is very useful.